# Finding button by XPath with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, button

I have been trying to locate the following button using Selenium WebDriver:

```
<div class="_1gw6tte">
    <div aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="_159vfsnv" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <div class="_12to336">
                <div class="_1ibtygfe">
                    <button type="button" class="_pmpl8qu">
                    Afficher plus de résultats</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used css selector, xpath, class and nothing seems to work (even by just copy pasting the one given by the inspector. The closest I've been is locating the div with the class _1ibtygfe)
Here is everything I tried, I'm desperate I don't understand why it does not locate it, it keeps throwing me a No Such Element exception.

```
wd.get(url)
print(wd.current_url) #check
#wd.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="ExploreLayoutController"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')#/div/div/div/button') #xpath given by inspector
#wd.find_element_by_class_name('_pmpl8qu')
#wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = '_1ibtygfe']/button[@class = '_pmpl8qu']")
#wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = '_1ibtygfe']/button")
#wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('button._pmpl8qu')
```

It's the airbnb website, I'm trying to **scrape** their events and clicking on the see more button. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: It's the airbnb website, I'm trying to scrape their events and clicking on the see more button - can you share the exact URL, I believe it's public. what do you mean by event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to click this button you need to

1. Close the "Accept cookies"
2. Scroll to that button since in is out of the visible screen area.
3. Click on it
   As following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://fr.airbnb.be/s/Montreal--QC/experiences?tab_id=experience_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fexperiences&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=june&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&rank_mode=default&place_id=ChIJDbdkHFQayUwR7-8fITgxTmU&checkin=2021-05-22")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid="accept-btn"]"))).click()

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Afficher plus de résultats')]")
actions.move_to_element(button).build().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
button.click()
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, what's an iframe? Here is the page with the button https://fr.airbnb.be/s/Montreal--QC/experiences?tab_id=experience_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fexperiences&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=june&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&rank_mode=default&place_id=ChIJDbdkHFQayUwR7-8fITgxTmU&checkin=2021-05-22

Comment: OK, I see. Are you trying to click that button?

Comment: Please see if updated code works. It should

Comment: Hey thanks for the edit but unfortunately it still does not work, still having the same error (NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element) at the line where trying to locate the button by xpath. I don't think scrolling it into view was the issue, i had tried scrapping info that was below that said button and I did not have any trouble with those...

Comment: Turns out I added time sleep between closing the cookies and finding the button and now it works !!! thank you so much

Comment: Great! Generally, it is always recommended to wait for each element visibility/presence etc. before each element access. It will make your test much stable. Also, if it was helpful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-testid='accept-btn']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Afficher plus de résultats']").click()
```